# Start app at startup in mac osx using python3?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

An app created with python3 & pyqt needs to be executed on startup.
Whenever the app gets executed it has to check whether it has been added to startup list, if not it should be added to the list so that by next time it should be executed on startup.

Is there a way to initiate an apple script using python3 or python3 itself to acheive this

Ideas would be very much appreciable?

Comment: Do I correctly understand your question? *How can I run an application when the operating system boots?* If that's the case, I'd suggest moving the question to superuser.

Comment: Question reframed to explain clearly

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good resource on how to add a login item via apple script:
http://macstuff.beachdogs.org/blog/?p=30

you can os.system to execute a osascript, for example:

```
cmd = """osascript<<END
tell application "iTunes"
play playlist "Party Shuffle"
end tell
END"""

os.system(cmd)
```

[more examples here](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2007/05/08/using-python-and-applescript-to-get-the-most-out-of-your-mac.html?page=2)

Comment: appears that both the hyperlinks are no longer functional. Would you mind linking to different resources? Just trying to see an example of adding/removing an app to/from startup apps on osx.